# Segmentation fault (11) in MPI Program

Tags: c++, mpi, virtualbox

I am creating a program to calculate the mean and standard deviation as well as print the array. When I am running the program, I am getting a segmentation fault error.

```
***Process received signal***
Signal: Segmentation fault(11)
Signal code: Address not mapped(1)
Failing at address: 0x1da8000
```

I cannot see any error in my code:

```
void printArray(int *array, int array_size){
for(int i = 0; i <array_size; i++){
    std::cout<<array[i]<<", ";
    if(i%10==9)
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

std::cout<<std::endl;
int sumArray(int *array, int array_size){
    int sum = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
       sum += array[i];
    return sum;
}

float sumDifferences(int *array, int size, int average){
    float sumDifference;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        float differenceSquare = (array[i]-average)*(array[i]-average);
        if(i==0)
            sumDifference = differenceSquare;
        else
            sumDifference = sumDifference= differenceSquare;
    }
    return sumDifference;
}
double fRand(double min, double max){
     double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
     return min + f * (max - min);
}
void coordinator(int world_rank, int world_size){
    int array_size = 100000;
    int array[array_size];
    int totalDiffSum;
    int totalMean;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <array_size; i++)
        array[i]=fRand(0, 51);
    int partition_size = array_size/world_size;
    std::cout<<"coordinator rank 0 partition size is " <<partition_size << std::endl;

    int *partition = new int[partition_size];
    MPI_Bcast(&partition_size, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(array, partition_size, MPI_INT, partition, partition_size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int sum = sumArray(partition, partition_size);
    int mean = sum / partition_size;
    MPI_Reduce(&mean, &totalMean, 1, MPI_LONG_LONG_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    int average = totalMean / world_size;

    MPI_Bcast(&average, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    int sumDiff = sumDifferences(partition, partition_size, average);

    MPI_Reduce(&sumDiff, &totalDiffSum, 1, MPI_LONG_LONG_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    double standardDeviation = sqrt(totalDiffSum / array_size);

    printArray(array,array_size);
    std::cout<<"Mean = "<<mean<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Standard Deviation = "<<standardDeviation<<std::endl;
    delete partition;
}

void participant(int world_rank,int world_size){
    int partition_size = 0;
    int totalMean;
    int totalDiffSum;
    int* array;

    MPI_Bcast(&partition_size, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    int *partition = new int[partition_size];

    MPI_Scatter(&array, partition_size, MPI_INT, partition, partition_size,MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    int sum = sumArray(partition, partition_size);
    int mean = sum / partition_size;

    MPI_Reduce(&mean, &totalMean, 1, MPI_LONG_LONG_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    int overallAverage = 0;

    MPI_Bcast(&overallAverage, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    int sumDiff = sumDifferences(partition, partition_size, overallAverage);

    MPI_Reduce(&sumDiff, &totalDiffSum, 1, MPI_LONG_LONG_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    delete partition;
 }
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
    int world_size,world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    if(world_rank==0)
        coordinator(world_rank,world_size);
    else
        participant(world_rank,world_size);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I would really appreciate any advice as I am new to c++ and I have never encountered this error before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is using `MPI_LONG_LONG_INT` in `MPI_Reduce` compatible with the fact that you are reducing over `int`'s? You are simply trashing the stack frame.

Comment: `int array_size = 100000;   int array[array_size];`  This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must be declared using a constant to denote the number of entries, not a variable.  I wouldn't be surprised if this alone is cause of the issue, since you could be blowing out the stack with a non-standard declaration like this.  In C++, dynamic arrays are done by using `std::vector`, or less desirable, `new[ ]`.

Comment: In addition `MPI_Scatter(&array,` -- Why are you passing the address of an uninitialized pointer?  That is probably where all the problems start. -- *I cannot see any error in my code:* -- Being new to C++, you won't see any errors, since a totally wrong program may be able to compile without errors.  Unless you know C++, you won't know what to look for.

Comment: Note that: `MPI_Scatter(void * send_data,...)`, you give it and address of a pointer. Change this`MPI_Scatter(&array,...)` to this: `MPI_Scatter(array,...)` and also make sure to initialize/allocate `array` before using it.